# Finding all the rectangles within a given rectangle that do not intersect with an arbitrary shape

Tags: algorithm, rectangles

I need to find an algorithm to find the *least* number of overlapping rectangles within a given rectangle R that do not intersect with the union of a set of *other* rectangles contained within R. These inner rectangles can overlap. Here's a terrible ASCII drawing of an example R:

```
A-----------------B-------------------------+
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                 +--------+                |
|                 |........|                |
|                 |........|                |
C             +---D........|                |
|             |.........+--+                |
|             |.........|                   |
|             ++........+------+            |
|              |...............|            |
G              +---H...........|            |
|                  |...........|            |
|                  |...........|            |
|                  |...........|            |
|                  +-----------+            |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
E-------------I----F------------------------+
```

The rectangles here would include (A, D), (A, I), (G, F). This seems like a problem for which the solution is well-understood, but for which I simply lack the vocabulary. Any answers, pointers, RTFMs cheerfully and gratefully accepted. Thanks!

EDIT: As per @Paul's observation below, what I'm trying to do is find a set of rectangles that cover the space in R without covering any of polygon comprised of the union of the inner set. If that makes sense.

Comment: i think you forgot to mention that the rectangles should fill the area that is in R, but not the union of given rectangles? Otherwise the answer is always 0

Comment: I'll try to find an answer as soon as i'm done with another problem

Comment: Could the overlapping rectangles create a bunch of "holes"? In other words can I have four rectangles partially adjacent to each other creating an internal region completely surrounded by r3ctanlges?

Comment: that'll take some time, but  i've found some helpful resources. btw, if you want to search on your own, the correct term for "union of a set of rectangles" would be "rectilinear polygon"

Comment: Thanks, good to know. As it happens, I don't need the smallest set or the largest tiles; realistically I'm willing to live with a suboptimal set if that makes the algorithm simpler to understand or faster to execute.

Comment: @RobertoAttias, theoretically, yes, although I'm happy to simplify the problem and pretend that the holes aren't there. Really, I'm looking for an approximate solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one possible way to solve.

I will refer to the overlapping rectangles as "white", and the ones in the solution as "black"

First of all, let's assume we have a data structure suitable for search on intersection. One possible data structure is an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), using points on one of the coordinates as intervals (for example, if a rectangle is defined by two points (x0,y0) and (x1, y1), use (x0, y1) as interval. The link also explain how to extend to higher dimensions (in your case you need 2).

I won't go in the detail of an implementation of such data structure, but let's assume we have one called `Rectangles`, with the following API defined:

- `void add(Rectangle r)`
- `void remove(Rectangle r)`
- `Rectangle[] getIntersecting(Rectangle r)`
- `Rectangle[] getAdjacent(Rectangle r)`

Ok, now create two instances of `Rectangles` called `black` and `white`. Initialize `white` with all the white rectangles. Initializie `black` with the `R` rectangle (the whole domain).

1. For each rectangle `rw` in `white` get the array `arr` of intersecting rectangles from black.
2. For each rectangle `rb` in `black`, determine the result of `rw-rb`. This is  a set `set` of 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 rectangles, depending on how the two rectangles intersect.
3. remove `rw` from `white`, and add the content of `set` to it. This may require merging rectangles from `set` with rectangle already in `white`, if such rectangles together form a larger rectangle (they're adjacent sharing one side)
4. remove `rb` from `black`
5. repeat from 1 until there are no more rectangles in `black`

Comment: How does it guarantee "the least number of overlapping rectangles"?

Comment: the requirement of "least number" was dropped by James Felix Black in a comment. I believe this algorithm produces the minimal set of non-overlapping rectangles, but it would take an extra effort to produce the minimal set of overlapping rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Using some basic math, we could say the solution to your problem would be the decomposition of the rectilinear polygon `R \ union(rs)`, where `union(rs)` represents the polygon inside `R`. Calculating `R \ union(rs)` can be done using the [Greiner-Hormann-algorithm](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/280000/274364/p71-greiner.pdf?ip=193.171.33.91&id=274364&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=9074CF143665B1C6.2D09E18E36C35C99.4D4702B0C3E38B35.4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=682356841&CFTOKEN=59798169&__acm__=1434030347_22c308acc146feb87f8cd757782864e0). Note that this step will result in a polygon with holes and - only if the inner polygon contains holes - multiple other polygons. The decomposition is described [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539799358835) (this is only an approximation, but i wasn't able to find a precise algorithm so far).